# Open password protected workbook via WorkbookOpen event

Tags: excel, vba

I have many workbooks that prompt for a password to open so I want to skip the step by using VBA to enter it for me. Is this possible? I am guessing no because the `WorkbookOpen` event doesn't fire until the book is open yes?

I have a class module in my personal.xlsb with the following code:

```
Private WithEvents appEvent As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set appEvent = Application
End Sub

Private Sub AppEvent_WorkbookOpen(ByVal wb As Excel.Workbook)

If wb.name = "PERSONAL.XLSB" Then Exit Sub

Dim prefix As String
Dim bookName As String
Dim path As String
Dim password As String
Dim dd As String
Dim book As Workbook

prefix = Left(wb.name, 3)

If prefix = "DD0" Then
    dd = Mid(wb.name, 4, 5)
    path = wb.path & "\"
    bookName = wb.name

    skipPass path, bookName, dd
End If

End Sub
```

Then I have a module in my personal.xlsb with the following:

```
Sub skipPass(p As String, n As String, center As String)

Dim book As Workbook
Set book = Workbooks.Open(filename:=p & n, UpdateLinks:=0, password:=pass(p, center))

End Sub

Function pass(path As String, ddN As String)

Select Case path
...
end function
```

The first time I open the workbook, it prompts me for the password. Then the code runs fine except it just loops forever. I think I can solve the loop problem by setting a global flag but how do I fix the first problem?

Comment: Do all workbooks have the same password?

Comment: No they do not hence `function pass`.

Answer (score 0):

This approach won't work since, as you've guessed, the `AppEvent_WorkbookOpen` event won't fire until you've supplied the password manually.

You have to handle the file opening yourself from the very beginning, i.e. by programming a sub that uses `Application.GetOpenFileName` to obtain one or more file names to open, and then supply passwords according to your logic. Your sub could be invoked by a key combination; search for `Application.OnKey` examples.

Note that string comparisons in VBA are case sensitive; use the [StrComp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/strcomp-function) function whenever you need to make case-insensitive comparisons.

Comment: The idea was to double click on a file and have it open without bothering entering a password but maybe this is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Created a class named `coa` with the following:

```
Private Type ddData
    path As String
    passw As String
End Type

Private this As ddData

Public Property Get path() As String
    path = this.path
End Property

Public Property Let path(ByVal value As String)
    this.path = value
End Property

Public Property Get passw() As String
    passw = this.passw
End Property

Public Property Let passw(ByVal value As String)
    this.passw = value
End Property
```

Then the following in a module:

```
Private Sub noPass()

Dim ddN As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim dd As coa

ddN = InputBox("File?")
If ddN = "" Then Exit Sub

dd = grabddData(ddN)
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=dd.path & ddN & ".xlsm", UpdateLinks:=0, password:=dd.passw)

End Sub

Private Function grabddData(ByVal ddNumber) As coa 'returns our class

Dim result As New coa 'create an object of our class

Select Case ddNumber
...
Set grabddData = result 'return our class object

End Function
```

Not ideal but oh well.